# How to check items of a table based on the defined access for user?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have two tables containing following columns:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [Id]
      ,[UserId]
      ,[MenuId]
      ,[parentid]
  FROM [TravelEnterDB].[dbo].[UserAccess]



SELECT TOP 1000 [Id]
      ,[Title]
      ,[parentId]
      ,[IsActive]
      ,[Url]
      ,[OrderMenu]
      ,[IconName]
  FROM [TravelEnterDB].[dbo].[AdminMenu]
```

so here is the deal,i want to show all of the 'AdminMenu' records with 'parenId=0' in a table in MVC and i want to tick the items which have been given to a specific user by 'UserId'.I have some codes but they are not working correctly.
Here is the code:

```
public ActionResult ADDAccess(int? id, string UserId)
 {
 List<MenuClass> model = new List<MenuClass>();
 var result =(from adminMenu in db.AdminMenus
 where adminMenu.parentId == 0
 select new
  {
    adminMenu.Id,
    adminMenu.IsActive,
    adminMenu.OrderMenu,
    adminMenu.Title,
    adminMenu.Url,
    adminMenu.parentId,
    adminMenu.IconName,
    });
     var users = db.UserAccesses.Where(p => p.UserId == UserId).ToList();
     var t = (from m in users
     join r in result on m.MenuId equals r.Id
    select new
                     {
                         r.Id,
                         r.IsActive,
                         r.OrderMenu,
                         r.Title,
                         r.Url,
                         r.parentId,
                         r.IconName,
                         m.UserId,
                         m.MenuId
                     }).ToList();
            foreach (var item in t)
            {
                MenuClass menu = new MenuClass();
                menu.IconName = item.IconName;
                menu.IsActive = item.IsActive;
                menu.Title = item.Title;
                menu.Url = item.Url;
                menu.Id = item.Id;
               if (item.Id == item.MenuId && item.UserId == UserId)
                 {
                   menu.IsChecked = true;
                 }
                menu.parentId = (int)item.parentId;
                model.Add(menu);
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```